# How do you receive a Bluetooth speaker's volume control messages in a WPF Windows desktop application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth speaker which has volume buttons that can control the volume on the source device.

I also have my own WPF music application that I would like to respond to the speaker's volume button clicks.

How can I do this?

I can see the device via this code below, but what can I do with it?

```
    DeviceInformationCollection result = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector());

    foreach (DeviceInformation info in result)
    {
        tbNotes.Text += info.Name + "\r\n";
    }
```

Is it necessary for me to read the messages directly from the Bluetooth speaker at all? or can I hook into a system wide message loop and intercept the volume clicks?

On second thoughts, it will have to be a direct receive from the device. The reason is if it were sending conventional VOLUME_UP and DOWN messages, Windows would have responded already. For some reasons only certain media applications are responding to it's volume commands:

**OK:**
Media Player (for Win 11)

**NOT OK:**
iTunes (Win 11);
VLC Player;
Windows Media Player (for Win 10)

Comment: Can you pair and connect to the speaker?

Comment: Pairing is fine, it's just that I can't control the device's volume from my music player windows application.

Comment: From your question, it seemed that you want to get your media player to detect when device's volume key is pressed. For that case, it would be pretty straight forward. Write a simple code to just connect with the device, get all services and characteristics, hook a callback to every notification characteristic, then press buttons on device. If the device is notifying its volume change, one of the notification characteristics will fire an event. Note down which service and characteristic it is and then enumerate the received binary data for each button press.

Comment: But if you want to control the device's volume from your media player, it gets a bit complicated. It depends on whether the device is accepting any data other than audio, what data and in what format. There is probably a standard signal for this, i.e., some data format used by all devices. Or you might have to refer to the device's documentation/manufacturer docs to see if it takes any such data.